# CiviEvent events partitioned by domain in WordPress multisite

Tags: wordpress, civievent, multisite, domain

I'm testing event management with CiviEvent in a CiviCRM/WordPress subdomain multisite installation (WordPress 4.9.8; CiviCRM 5.4.0). Is there any built-in support for segregating events by the CiviCRM domain ID (which maps to a WordPress site/subdomain)?

If not, can you suggest a practical way of partitioning or filtering events by WordPress site/subdomain? Ideally, I'd like local WordPress site administrators to only be able to view and manage events for their own WP site/subdomain in CiviEvent.

Most events will be public, but it would be great to have a solution where non-public events can also be partitioned by Civi domain ID.

Comment: I believe that work was started but not completed on this by Cividesk.  I suggest reaching out to them to see if it's available on a public repository somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to post a belated update here, in case it helps someone else or could trigger additional discussion or action. Per Jon G, I emailed CiviDesk and got a prompt response:

> We have developed multisite support for events in CiviCRM, and it has
>   been in production for several years now with one of our largest
>   customers. The code is public, but not documented or guaranteed and
>   delivered as-is, without any support from us.... It is available in
>   https://github.com/cividesk/civicrm-core/tree/4.7.31-cividesk-arcs, it
>   contains a lot of patches in addition to just the multisite changes.
>   We will be migrating this customer to CiviCRM 5.7 ESR in H1 2019, and
>   port all to this newer version then.

CiviDesk further clarified that the customization does *not* currently include 'packaging' for this feature (i.e. setup screens, documentation, test suite, ...). It cannot become part of the official CiviCRM release without these. If there were interest and funding (via a "*Make it happen*" project or similar), they could move forward on this.

I had hoped to dig into the code to explore further, but haven't yet because of limited time and other priorities. For the short term, we're using a WordPress-only multisite compatible events management solution. For the longer term, a solution integrated with CiviCRM would be preferable. With guidance from more experienced Civi developers, I'd be willing to pitch in.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a Custom Field to the events, and then use CiviCRM ACLs to restrict folk based on the value of that Custom Field. If that isn't viable then setting up civicrm to proper multisite might be a viable but complex route